# does post-redirect-get need to happen for an ajax request?

Tags: ajax, http-post, idempotent

is there any reason to use the post-redirect-get (prg) for a request that you know will only happen via an ajax request?

in this scenario, you might have a request that is sent (either via ajax or direct), and we're assuming on the back-end we can distinguish which is which. In the case where the direct request is handled using prg, is there any reason to also handle the *ajax* request with a prg too?

or can an ajax post just be responded to directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something that only uses AJAX, I can't see a reason to use prg. Since it is not a user controlled action with the possibility of duplication, the only way the AJAX call would be duplicated is if the original page was refreshed before the action finished, and since prg has that same one flaw, you may as well use the direct approach.

Comment: out of interest, could you elaborate on the "page reloading" issue? Why would a page reload re-send a request that was already sent?

Comment: When I originally read your question, for some reason I assumed that your AJAX call was tied to an onload event, which really had no bearing on my answer anyways and just confused it.  At any rate, I was trying to explain that prg seems useless for AJAX, because the whole point of prg is to guard against a user resubmitting a form by refreshing a page, and AJAX is meant to happen without a page refresh and therefore cannot be guarded against using prg. This is a reference that matches my understanding of prg and may help frame my opinion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get